# Using polymorphic queries over interfaces in RavenDB

Tags: c#, database, nosql, ravendb, document-database

I'm interested in switching over our application (or parts of it) to use RavenDB from SQL server with NHibernate.

The key feature that I can't seem to find in Raven is the usage of interfaces for queries eg:

```
ISearchable
{
  string Name {get;set;}
}

Class1 : ISearchable
{
  string Name {get;set;}
}
Class2 : ISearchable
{
   string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In NH I can search for the contents of the Name field in any ISearchable: `QueryOver<ISearchable>()`.

I can't seem to find this in Raven, am I missing something? The closest that I've found is changing the string part at the front of the identifier, which I don't want to do; the main function of Class1 and Class2 is not to be searchable!

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an index like:

```
// ByName
from doc in docs
select new { doc.Name }
```

session.Query("ByName");

Comment: How to define such index in C#? Actually what TDocument to use for  IndexDefinitionBuilder<TDocument> to query "in docs" and not "in docs.TDocument" ?